# CakePHP-3.5.4 - Reverse routing not working as expected

Tags: cakephp, routes, url-routing, cakephp-3.0

In my routes.php file I define:

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect(
        '/',
        [
            'plugin' => false,
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'dashboard'
        ],
        ['_name' => 'admin_dashboard']
    );
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

In controller, i do:

```
debug(Router::url(['_name' => 'admin_dashboard']));
```

It prints `/admin`  which is **correct**.

But if, in the same controller, i do:

```
debug(Router::url([
    'prefix' => 'admin',
    'plugin' => false,
    'controller' => 'Users',
    'action' => 'dashboard'
]));
```

It prints `/admin/users/dashboard` which is **incorrect**, at least i think as i expect it to print `/admin`.

Is there something I am missing out in order to make **reverse routing** work?

I am using CakePHP 3.5.4

Answer (score 0):

The `plugin` key doesn't really support booleans, the value should be either a string with the name of the plugin, or `null` to indicate that no plugin should be used.

Using `false` will cause the route to not be matched, and instead it's being catched by the fallback routes, hence you end up with the `/admin/users/dashboard` URL.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Creating Links to Plugin Routes](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#creating-links-to-plugin-routes)**